# Matriz transpuesta con arreglos unidimensionales,

Tags: c, matrices, random, matriz, fórmulas-de-matriz

debo obtener la matriz transpuesta sin usar la sintaxis [][], solo usando vectores unidimensionales, intenté obtener el nuevo índice que debería tener cada valor en la matriz transpuesta, pero al imprimirlo los datos no me dan mucho sentido, muchas gracias de antemano.

La matriz original debe llenarse con valores aleatorios

```
{
            int n;
            int total;
            int num_ran;
                
            srand(time(NULL));
         
     total=rows*cols;
     
     for(n=0;n<total;n++)
    
        matrix_original [n]=rand() % (100);
        

            
        }
    /*
     * TODO:
     * Transpose the original matrix and store the resulting elements in
     * the 'matrix_transposed' array.
     * You can declare as many variables as you need.
     */

{    
     int i,x,n,r,c;
     int total;
     
        total=rows*cols;
        for(n=0;n<total;n++)
        
            for(i=0;i<total;i++)
                r=i/cols;
                c=i%cols;
                i=r*cols+c;
            
        matrix_transposed[n]=matrix_original[n];
        
}
```

The original matrix is:
73      44      46
76      59      78
The transposed matrix is:
-2131546144     32765
4195936 76
-2131545920     32765

Esto obtengo si intento correrlo, no estoy muy segura de que está haciendo con los valores originales.

Comment: Publica un ejemplo con matriz de entrada y matriz de salida, para poder chequear que las respuestas sean correctas.

Comment: Cuando salen valores de ese tipo, usualmente estas accediendo a memoria que no te corresponde. Para saber donde lo estas haciendo te recomiendo que uses un adress sanitizer y que imprimas cada valor al que estas accediendo.

Comment: No muestras cómo  creas los arrays, tampoco como imprimes los valores. Por favor, proporciona un ejemplo **mínimo** y **completo** que reproduzca el problema. Si no lo haces dificilmente vamos a ser capaces de darte una solución